# Splunk - Extracted number from search result not showing up in the table

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

My splunk result looks like this:

```
9/1/20
5:00:14.487 PM  
2020-09-01 16:00:14.487, 'TOTALITEMS'="Number of items registered in the last 2 hours ", COUNT(*)="1339"
```

I am trying to table the number that appears in the end in quotes.

```
index=my_db sourcetype=no_of_items_registered source=P_No_of_items_registered_2hours | rex field=_raw "\"Number of items registered in the last 2 hours \", COUNT(\*)=\"(?P<itm_ct>\d+)\"$" | table itm_ct
```

This displays a blank table without any numbers. The number of rows in the table however matches the the number of events.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression doesn't match the sample data.  Literal parentheses must be escaped in the regex.  Try this:

```
index=my_db sourcetype=no_of_items_registered source=P_No_of_items_registered_2hours 
| rex "COUNT\(\*\)="(?<itm_ct>\d+)" | table itm_c
```